# running multiple sqls one needed to be run first then the two to be run together PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am very new to PHP. I am trying to run these sqls. The first sql is needed to be runned first in order to get the value needed to be inserted to the two remaining sqls.

Here is what I done:

```
$sql = "SELECT (unitPrice) FROM product WHERE productID = '".$pid."'";
$sql1 = "INSERT INTO order (orderID) VALUES ('".$rnd_id."');";
$sql1 .= "INSERT INTO order_details (orderID,orderType,orderDate,orderTime,quantity,orderPrice,discount,discountPrice,employeeID) VALUES ('".$rnd_id."','".$type."','".$date."','".$time."','".$quantity."','".$oprice."','".$dis."','".$dprice."','".$eid."')";

        if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                $price = $row['unitPrice'];
                $oprice = (double)$price * (double)$quantity;
            }   
        } else{
            echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
        }

        $dprice = $oprice - $oprice * $dis;

        //Free result set
        mysqli_free_result($result);

        if(mysqli_multi_query($link, $sql1)){
            do {
                /* store first result set */
                if ($result = mysqli_store_result($link)) {     
                    mysqli_free_result($result);
                }
            } while (mysqli_next_result($link));
                //Records created successfully. Redirect to landing page
                header("location: index5.php");
                exit(); 
        } else{
            echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
        }
```

Comment: There’s a couple of things you need to change in your approach.  1) Before you try to do anything complicated, learn the right way to do queries: use prepared statements. It’s better to learn it now, rather than going back to fix your code later. 2) you can’t assign a variable before you get it. You’ve defined your queries before you even have the values they’re supposed to hold.

Comment: everything needed to be inserted has a value except for the oprice and dprice. The unitPrice from product is needed to be known in order to equate the two. After that, the two variables with the provided values for other variables should be inserted as said in the two remaining statements.

Comment: Don't name your table `order`. **ORDER**  is a reserved name in mysql and this only will bring you trouble.

Comment: will it work after doing that?

Comment: No, there's a lot wrong with your code. I'm writing you an answer, but it takes a bit.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: you really should use prepared statements. It is not only a lot safer, but also makes your life easier as you can write far cleaner code.
[Read this](http://bobby-tables.com/) on the why and [this page](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) on the how. In the example below I'm using PDO.

The first thing wrong with your code: you use variables before they are defined. Look at

```
$sql1 .= [...] VALUES 
('".$rnd_id."','".$type."','".$date."','".$time."','".$quantity."',
'".$oprice."','".$dis."','".$dprice."','".$eid."')";
```

`$oprice` and `$dprice` are used, but they are defined only later in your code. So they don't have a value on the moment you construct the query.

Second: take a look at the [reserved words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html) in mysql.
**ORDER** is a reserved word, you shouldn't use it for a table name.

Then, you use a seperate **SELECT** query to get the price and then use it in the INSERt query. It is not necessary. Databases are quite good at combining tables. So you can use a SELECT with your INSERT, combining the price from `product` with the INSERT in `order_details`

I suppose the variables `$rnd_id, $type, $quantity, $dis` are defined somewhere else, as that's not shown in your code.

Using a prepared statement, inserting `$rnd_id` can be written like this:

```
//construct a query with :rnd_id as a parameter
$query= 'INSERT INTO order_id (orderID) VALUES (:rnd_id)';

//bind the variable to the parameter
$bind=[
    ':rnd_id'=>$rnd_id
    ];

//prepare the statement
$statement = $link->prepare($query);
//execute the statement
$statement->execute($bind);
```

The second INSERT uses a SELECT to get the product price from the `product` table. As you can see, I let mysql do the calculations in the query, so no need to do it in seperate code.

Instead of using `$date` and `$time` I simply tell mysql to use the current date and time with `NOW()`

Why I use multiple parameters for `quantity` and `discount`: sadly PDO can't re-use a parameter. So if you want to use it again in the query, you have to define it again.

```
$query = ' 
INSERT INTO order_details (
    orderID,
    orderType,
    orderDate,
    orderTime,
    quantity,
    orderPrice,
    discount,
    discountPrice, 
    employeeID
    )
SELECT 
    :rnd_id ,
    :type   ,
    NOW()   ,
    NOW()   ,
    :quant1 ,
    (unitPrice * :quant2), //'unitPrice from table product, mysql does the calculation'
    :disc1  ,
    (unitPrice * :quant3) - ((unitPrice * :quant4) * :disc2) ,
    :empID
FROM product WHERE productID = :prodID
';

$bind=[
    ':rnd_id'   =>$rnd_id,
    ':type'     =>$type,
    ':quant1'   =>$quantity,
    ':quant2'   =>$quantity,
    ':quant3'   =>$quantity,
    ':quant4'   =>$quantity,
    ':disc1'    =>$dis,
    ':disc2'    =>$dis,
    ':prodID'   =>$pid,
    ':empID'    =>$eid
    ];
$statement = $link->prepare($query);
$statement->execute($bind);
```

There's a lot more say about your code, but this covers the basics. I've tested the queries (they work), but not the PHP code. So there could be an error in there somewhere.

Comment: I am having trouble when the two codes are encoded. $statement->execute($bind);
is causing a problem in the first code.